# Using PowerShell to Append a number to the beginning of a filename when using a reference csv as input

Tags: powershell

I'm hoping someone out there already has a handy bit of PowerShell or similar to help me out with this. It's a one-off task, but one that would take days/weeks to run through manually. I'll keep the objective as simple as possible.

I have few thousand files in a directory with the following format:
*BL_string1_string2.pdf*

All the names of these files need changing so that a corresponding unique string and underscore is added to the start of the file name, like so:
*string3_BL_string1_string2.pdf*

The values required for each file are recorded as columns in rows of a SQL db table. I have exported this data in values exported in a csv with headers for all the string1 & string3 values for these files.

How can use the csv as an input to automate the renaming of these files?

Example:

Csv has 2 columns/headers: "string1" and "string3" (the "string2" value is immaterial).

If "string1" for a row is abc123 and"string3" for that row is 456xyz, the corresponding file to be renamed would be renamed from "BL_abc123_blah.pdf" to "456xyz_BL_abc123_blah.pdf

I can get by with PowerShell when required, but the mechanics of this one are a little beyond me I'm afraid. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not show us this csv file you want to use and give us some real examples?

Comment: Not sure how to upload the csv file itself, but it has 2 columns/headers: "string1" and "string3" (the "string2" value is immaterial). If "string1" for a row is abc123 and "string3" for that row is 456xyz, the corresponding file to be renamed would be renamed from "BL_abc123_blah.pdf" to "456xyz_BL_abc123_blah.pdf". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for explaining further in your comment.

If you say you have thousands of files to rename, using a Hashtable for looking up the prefix string would be the fastest way to go.

```
# Import the csv file and then convert the resulting array of objects into a Hashtable for speed
$csvDtata   = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\SomeWhere\replacements.csv'
$lookupHash = @{}
# each Key will be the string to compare against, the Value is the prefix for the file name
# string1 and string3 are the headers in the csv file
foreach ($item in $csvDtata) { $lookupHash[$item.string1] = $item.string3 }  

# get a list of files from the folder
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\PathTo\TheFiles' -Filter 'BL_*_*.pdf' -File
# loop over this list and rename where needed
foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
    $compare = ($file.Name -split '_')[1]  # take the decisive part of the name ('string1')
    if ($lookupHash.ContainsKey($compare)) {
        # we have a match, rename the file. 
        ##### See Note below #####
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}' -f $lookupHash[$compare], $file.Name) -WhatIf
    }
}
```

**Note**: I have added `-WhatIf` to the Rename-Item cmdlet for safety. That switch then only outputs on screen what *would* be renamed,
but nothing will actually happen to the file. Once you are sure that output shows the correct renaming results, remove `-WhatIf` and run the script again.

As always, first try this out on a couple of test files

Comment: Thank you Theo, this is precisely what I needed and has saved me a lot messing around. I had a feeling hashtables or arrays were the way to go with it, but I've never really got my head round the syntax. Cheers buddy!